# Chrome Extension Block a certain pattern of url

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-webrequest

I am building a chrome extension that blocks images from a certain host address. However, as google proxies the images, I am not able to figure out the url pattern to use in chrome webrequest api.

The url would be something like this.

https://ci6.googleusercontent.con/proxy/hashds93932932-0-3123_#https://targethost.com/track?=trackparams

Comment: Since the API ignores the #hash part in URL patterns, you'll have to use a generic pattern like `https://*.googleusercontent.con/proxy/hashds*`, then check `details.url` string for `targethost` substring inside your webRequest listener.

Comment: @wOxxOm So what I need to do is to use regex to check details.url. If that returns true then I return {cancel : true} otherwise {cancel : false}

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so as @wOxxOm pointed out that I need to check the value of details.url. { details is what that webrequest API returns in the callback}. I needed to apply regex on the link and that worked for me. If regex fails then return {cancel:false} otherwise {cancel:true}. cancel:true blocks the web request.